# Set a condition based on WooCommerce checkout city field while placing order

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, email

How to make condition on WooCommerce checkout field like when user select city "Indore" then on place order email goes to `indore@gmail.com` and when he select "Bhopal" city then email goes to `bhopal@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The following code will add an additional recipient based on customer billing/shipping city, to new order admin notification:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'different_email_recipients', 10, 2 );
function different_email_recipients( $recipient, $order ) {
    if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) 
        return $recipient;

    $city = $order->get_shipping_city();
    $city = empty( $city ) ? $order->get_billing_city() : $city;

    // Conditionaly send additional email based on customer city
    if ( 'Indore' == $city ) 
    {
        $recipient .= ',indorel@gmail.com';
    } 
    elseif ( 'bhopal' == $city ) 
    {
        $recipient .= ',bhopal@gmail.com';
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: email not recieving to recipents

Comment: @HakimuddinSaifee Sorry I forgot some little things… I have updated the code and it should work now.

Comment: thanks Alot @LoicTheAztec its working

Comment: ok thanks alot i will accept